# probability density function of a function of a uniform random variable

Tags: probability

First a point Y is selected at random from the interval (0,1). Then another point X is selected at random from the interval (Y,1). Find the probability density function of X.

Comment: Please at least *try* something (and *show* it) so we may see what trouble you are having with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The joint density function of $(X,Y)$ is given by,

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y) $$

where $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ is the conditional pdf of $X | Y \sim Unif(Y,1)$ and $f_Y(y)$ is the marginal pdf of $Y \sim Unif(0,1)$. You can find the marginal pdf of $X$ from this by doing an appropriate integration.